# Why next js image optimizer adding domain path before remote image url?

Tags: next.js

In my app I am using ExportedImage from https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-image-export-optimizer library like this.

```
import ExportedImage from 'next-image-export-optimizer'

<ExportedImage src={media?.original_url} fill sizes="100vw" alt={title} placeholder="em>
```

`media.original_url is equal to 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/getnarval-test/domains/9909f63c-9b13-48a9-9d2d-ea01a7b37c95/1/person.jpg'`

when app is open image is properly displayed but i have an error in console:

[image]

Any ideas why next is adding domain name before real url?

my next.config file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: true,
    openAnalyzer: true
})

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    compiler: {
        styledComponents: true
    },
    images: {
        loader: 'custom',
        imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
        deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: '*.amazonaws.com',
                pathname: '**'
            },
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: 'eu.ui-avatars.com',
                pathname: '**'
            }
        ]
    },
    env: {
        nextImageExportOptimizer_imageFolderPath: 'public/img',
        nextImageExportOptimizer_exportFolderPath: 'out',
        nextImageExportOptimizer_quality: 75,
        nextImageExportOptimizer_storePicturesInWEBP: true,

        // If you do not want to use blurry placeholder images, then you can set
        // nextImageExportOptimizer_generateAndUseBlurImages to false and pass
        // `placeholder="empty"` to all <ExportedImage> components.
        //
        // If nextImageExportOptimizer_generateAndUseBlurImages is false and you
        // forget to set `placeholder="empty"`, you'll see 404 errors for the missing
        // placeholder images in the console.
        nextImageExportOptimizer_generateAndUseBlurImages: true
    },
    trailingSlash: true
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

What i found is when i put url like this :

`src="//s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/getnarval-test/domains/9909f63c-9b13-48a9-9d2d-ea01a7b37c95/1/person.jpg"`

so without any http or https in the begginning it looks better because not caontain host name but next treat is as http. I need to found a way how to map // to https.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your remote url,One slash is missing in url and next is recognizing this as URL Subdirectory:

`https:/www...` should be `https://...`

Comment: What is weird that from API im am getting https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/getnarval-test/domains/9909f63c-9b13-48a9-9d2d-ea01a7b37c95/1/person.jpg so with https: // but next is recogniziong it as https:/

Comment: @obaram ``media.original_url is equal to 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/getnarval-test/domains/9909f63c-9b13-48a9-9d2d-ea01a7b37c95/1/person.jpg'`` appears when you do console.log in media.original_url?

Comment: did you configure the lib in next.config.js?

Comment: Yesm please take a look at my main post I have just edited it.

Comment: your next.config.js contains transpilePackages and env propertys? if so, can you add in post?

Comment: I just updated main post, whole next.config.js added